# How to specify table class with django_tables2

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-tables2

I am wanting to use the bootstrap table design shown here:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/

The table class is called ""

My issue is I dont understand how to implement this with a django_tables2 table. I have utilized the bootstrap templates that they give in their documentation but none of them look very good. How would I use these other table class options given by bootstrap?

```
class PersonTable(tables.Table):
class Meta:
    model = player_hardware
    template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap-responsive.html"
```

Comment: I don't believe you are going to find a true design as you want, plug-and-play option (I use something similar and I style customly)...with that simply write CSS or override styling with JS on load...styling is not really programmatic or logic based, just style as you need when the page renders, CSS fixes the rest

Answer (score 1):

You can add class attributes to the table in the Table's Meta class. Just add what classes you want on the table, make sure you're loading the css file in the webpage, and bootstrap css will do the rest.

More info here:
https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-rendering.html#css

```
class PersonTable(tables.Table):

    class Meta:
        model = player_hardware
        attrs = {"class": "table table-sm table-striped"}
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap-responsive.html"
```